# Why don't we use the data type for function parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript if I have to use a variable foo then I have to first define it as `var foo`. But when we use parameters in functions, e.g. as:

```
function myfunc(bar) {  
  alert(bar);  
}
```

why don't we write `function myfunc(var bar) {...}` instead? How does javascript know that `bar` is a variable? I remember that in C++ we have to tell that the compiler that the parameter being passed to the function is a variable as

`int myfunc ( char bar[] ) {...}`

Comment: Because it's the only valid thing to go there, what else would it be?

Comment: JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. It knows that `bar` is a parameter because that's the only thing it can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `foo = bar` is ambiguous, it could be the initialisation of a new variable, or it could be assigning a value to an existing variable. Since that's important with regards to scope in Javascript, you need to explicitly use `var foo` for initialising a new variable.

`function (foo)` on the other hand is entirely unambiguous. `foo` is a function parameter and therefore also functions as a variable initialiser. There's no point in distinguishing between `function (var foo)` and `function (foo)`, both of them would do the same thing.

`myfunc ( char bar[] )` in C does something completely different; `char` here is a *type hint*. Javascript doesn't have type hints. It only has the `var` keyword (and related `let` and `const`) for initialising new variables, but that doesn't have anything to do with types or type hints.

Answer (score 2):

Because `JS` doesn't support it. Simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

> How does javascript know that `bar` is a variable?

Because all parameters of functions are local variables in JavaScript.

And in contrast to C++, variables don't have a type, so you don't have to (and cannot) specify types for function parameters either.

Answer (score 0):

As James111 said. Javascript does not support adding types to input parameters.

If you really want this functionality, you can use a language that compiles down to Javascript. For example [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/).

If you want to program in pure Javascript you can use visual studio code, since it has some [nice commenting features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/user_ed/2016/02/09/visual-studio-code-new-features-javascript-salsa-preview/) for tagging input parameters